# Dashboard reports with nice Charts & UI in Marketing CLoud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, dashboard, analytics, custom-reports

Is there a way to get nice dashboards and charts/graphs in analytics builder? Most reports are simply .csv exports and the only other area I see nice charts and dashboards is in the tracking > reports in Email studio and looking at some of the built in dashboards in Journey Builder. I also have discover reporting that I'm playing around with and it's ok.

Is Marketing Cloud devoid of meaningful UI dashboard reports that you can build and export or am I missing something?

Comment: Out-of-the-box Marketing Cloud reporting is pretty bare bones for a product at this price point. Better options are available for more money, such as the Google Analytics 360 integration. 

However, for the sort of thing you're after, you'd probably be better off exporting the raw data and analysing it in a BI tool.